# prompt is not is not showing in the script

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Please see the code below and tell me where I am doing wrong. There is no alert showing when I run this script on my computer. I have checked many times but I didn't get it why this is not working.

```
var day = prompt("Type any weekday name.");



if(day == "Monday") {
    alert("Go to School");
} else if(day == "Tuesday") {
    alert("Go to market")'
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly. While I edited your question to make it more readable your actual code in the files on your PC should look as good/structured as the code in your question now does.

Comment: Thank you @ThiefMaster As you can see I am new to this forum and to web development so I need some time to understand all this stuff and can you please tell me how can I indent code as you did?

Comment: Simply use a proper editor/IDE that takes care of the indentation automatically. If you for some reason still use a plaintext editor such as notepad you should switch to something more advanced as soon as possible.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Thank you for your time and help, next time I will be more careful to post code with proper indention.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax highligting points out your mistake - a syntax error caused by a `'` where you wanted a `;` (or nothing, as semicolons are usually optional in JavaScript):

```
alert("Go to market")'
```

Corrected:

```
alert("Go to market");
// or
alert("Go to market")
```

Comment: ohh, how can I forgot this little mistake. Thank you @ThiefMaster, now it's working fine.